# Azure java function : No HTTP triggers found when deploying

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I just wrote a new function with java runtime 17. Locally, I am able to run the azure function but the deployment is giving "No HTTP triggers found.". This started happening today. It was working till yesterday. Not sure what has changed for java on jan 31st 2024.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Deployment:

```
10:29:46 PM njs123: c:\trunk\jj\build\tmp\jar\MANIFEST.MF
10:29:46 PM njs123: c:\trunk\jj\build\azure-functions\jj-1706844397343\host.json
10:29:46 PM njs123: c:\trunk\jj\build\azure-functions\jj-1706844397343\local.settings.json
10:29:46 PM njs123: c:\trunk\jj\build\azure-functions\jj-1706844397343\HttpTriggerJava1\function.json
10:29:46 PM njs123: c:\trunk\jj\build\azure-functions\jj-1706844397343\jj-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
10:29:46 PM njs123: c:\trunk\jj\build\azure-functions\jj-1706844397343\lib\azure-functions-java-core-library-1.0.0.jar
10:29:46 PM njs123: c:\trunk\jj\build\libs\jj-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
10:29:46 PM njs123: c:\trunk\jj\build\classes\java\main\com\fun
```

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;

public class HttpTriggerJava1 {
@FunctionName("HttpTriggerJava1")
public HttpResponseMessage run(
        @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, 
HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.FUNCTION) 
  HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
        final ExecutionContext context) {
    context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a 
    request.");
    String query = request.getQueryParameters().get("name");
    String name = request.getBody().orElse(query);
    if (name == null) {
        return 
request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Please 
pass a name on the query string or in the request body").build();
    } else {
        return 
request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello, " + 
name).build();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code and configuration that proves that you have defined the triggers correctly

Comment: hosts.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
local.settings.json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java"
  }
}
In the deployment command response it is showing the function.json which looks like this in my next comment.

Comment: {
  "scriptFile" : "../jj-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar",
  "entryPoint" : "com.function.HttpTriggerJava1.run",
  "bindings" : [ {
    "type" : "httpTrigger",
    "direction" : "in",
    "name" : "req",
    "methods" : [ "GET", "POST" ],
    "authLevel" : "FUNCTION"
  }, {
    "type" : "http",
    "direction" : "out",
    "name" : "$return"
  } ]
}

Comment: This is sample code autogenerated which I am trying to deploy.

Comment: All I did is in visual code ,
Create new function-> selected java runtime, created HTTP Trigger which generates default code. And ran locally. And later deployed on azure.

Comment: Please edit your post to include this information in a way that we can read it, In this format it is very hard to follow.

Comment: Added hosts.json in the first question

Comment: I can't help with java, but on the surface this checks out as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.httptrigger?view=azure-java-stable

Answer (score 0):

***I was facing the same issue while deploying Java Http Triggered Azure function using Visual Studio code.***

To resolve this, I have **downgraded Azure Functions Extension version to 1.13.1** in `Visual Studio Code=>Extensions=> Search for Azure Functions=>click on drop down of Uninstall->select Install other version=>select 1.13.1 version`.

[image]

**Local response:**

[image]

```java
9:48:10 PM: Running command: "mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId="com.microsoft.azure" -DarchetypeArtifactId="azure-functions-archetype" -DarchetypeVersion="LATEST" -DjavaVersion="17" -DgroupId="com.function" -DartifactId="javafn" -Dversion="1.0-SNAPSHOT" -Dpackage="com.function" -DappName="javafn-1707149882549" -B"...
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> archetype:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< archetype:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- archetype:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[INFO] Archetype repository not defined. Using the one from [com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-archetype:1.52] found in catalog remote
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Archetype: azure-functions-archetype:LATEST
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: com.function
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: javafn
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: com.function
[INFO] Parameter: packageInPathFormat, Value: com/function
[INFO] Parameter: resourceGroup, Value: java-functions-group
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: com.function
[INFO] Parameter: appName, Value: javafn-1707149882549
[INFO] Parameter: javaVersion, Value: 17
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: com.function
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: javafn
[INFO] Parameter: appServicePlanName, Value: java-functions-app-service-plan
[INFO] Parameter: trigger, Value: HttpTrigger
[INFO] Parameter: appRegion, Value: westus
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Parameter: docker, Value: false
[INFO] Executing META-INF/archetype-post-generate.groovy post-generation script
[INFO] Project created from Archetype in dir: C:\Users\uname\AppData\Local\Temp\38be4356cf\javafn
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.489 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-05T21:48:24+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished running command: "mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId="com.microsoft.azure" -DarchetypeArtifactId="azure-functions-archetype" -DarchetypeVersion="LATEST" -DjavaVersion="17" -DgroupId="com.function" -DartifactId="javafn" -Dversion="1.0-SNAPSHOT" -Dpackage="com.function" -DappName="javafn-1707149882549" -B".
9:50:28 PM pravjavafunc: Stopping app...
9:50:30 PM pravjavafunc: Starting deployment...
9:50:30 PM pravjavafunc: Creating zip package...
9:50:30 PM pravjavafunc: Zip package size: 20.3 kB
9:50:54 PM pravjavafunc: Updating submodules.
9:50:54 PM pravjavafunc: Preparing deployment for commit id '818babcf62'.
9:50:55 PM pravjavafunc: Skipping build. Project type: Run-From-Zip
9:50:55 PM pravjavafunc: Skipping post build. Project type: Run-From-Zip
9:50:55 PM pravjavafunc: Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
9:50:56 PM pravjavafunc: Deployment successful.
9:50:59 PM pravjavafunc: Starting app...
9:51:11 PM pravjavafunc: Syncing triggers...
9:51:15 PM pravjavafunc: Querying triggers...
9:51:20 PM pravjavafunc: HTTP Trigger Urls:
  HttpExample: https://pravjavafunc.azurewebsites.net/api/httpexample
```

**Portal:**

[image]

**Response:**

[image]